# Chainable operations on lists

Tags: python

I want to do something like

```
list = [6,4,1,10,8].sort().reverse()
```

or

```
zip([x**2 for x in xrange(5)], [x**3 for x in xrange(5)].reverse()])
```

but this doesn't work because methods on list doesn't return the original object, so they're not chainable.

Do I have to do this using multiple lines or is there some cool functional programming magic I can do in python to achieve this in one line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed).

Answer (score 7):

```
reversed(sorted([6,4,1,10,8]))
```

The [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) and [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) builtins have been around since Python 2.4.

Note that you should do `sorted(my_list, reverse=True)` if you are going to reverse the list immediately.

Comment: Also, `reversed()` returns an iterator, not a list, so use `list(reversed(sorted(...)))` as necessary.